# TFS 2013 Nightly build failure is not making BUG work item on test failure (VSO)

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-workitem, nightly-build

We are using VSO for everything and builds are handled through our own build server.
Everything is working fine however for all nightly builds, when they fail on tests (the whole point of nightly builds), it is not generating a new bug.

There are no errors that I can see on build result even on the diagnostic logging verbosity. 
What I see is that, it never gets into section to generate work item on build failure.

It does not even try to make a work item.

I tried several different settings as well.
Associate Changesets and Work Items: True or False [Final value True]
Label Sources: True or False [Final Value True]
Create Work Item on Failure: Always True

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not supported on TFS2013. This feature seems to have been incorporated on Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 - see below quote [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/tfs2015-update2-vs.aspx)

> New version of web-based Release Management - You can create bugs for
>   failed tests. Debug information, like error message and stack trace,
>   will be auto-populated in the bug.